# jQuery - Combing "each" with an "on" event

Tags: jquery, each

I have the following jQuery code which works fine and does eveyrthing I need - just seems to be a bit of a clumsy way of achieving what I need - ie. the actual "function" is identical in both parts - the first part gives me the current value on entering the page, the second part dynamically changes the value on input into the textarea. My question is, is there a way to "neatly" combiine the two halves to just have the function appear once - would make editing easier later:

```
$("textarea.charcount").each(function() {
    var maxlength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
    var currentLength = $(this).val().length;
    if( currentLength >= maxlength ){
        $(this).next('div').addClass('limit');
        $(this).next('div').text("Character limit reached!");
    } else {
        $(this).next('div').removeClass("limit");
        $(this).next('div').text(maxlength - currentLength + " charachters left");
    }
});

$("textarea.charcount").on("input", function() {
    var maxlength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
    var currentLength = $(this).val().length;
    if( currentLength >= maxlength ){
        $(this).next('div').addClass('limit');
        $(this).next('div').text("Character limit reached!");
    } else {
        $(this).next('div').removeClass("limit");
        $(this).next('div').text(maxlength - currentLength + " charachters left");
    }
});
```

Comment: What about instead of the each maybe doing something like `$("textarea.charcount").trigger('input')` to leverage the `on` you already have. I suggest making a jsfiddle so we can play with it

Comment: How about making it a function and calling that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add like this,

```
$(function(){   
    $("textarea.charcount").each(function(){
        charcount(this);
    });
    $("textarea.charcount").on("input", function() {
        charcount(this);
    });
});
function charcount(element){
    var maxlength = $(element).attr("maxlength");
    var currentLength = $(element).val().length;
    if( currentLength >= maxlength ){
        $(element).next('div').addClass('limit').text("Character limit reached!");
    } else {
        $(element).next('div').removeClass("limit").text(maxlength - currentLength + " charachters left");
    }
}
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/rhqtc67a/

Comment: Brilliant - the ideal solution for my needs - many thanks :-)

Comment: And extremly compact and tidy to boot - awesome

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$("textarea.charcount").each(function() {
  YourFunction($(this))
});

$("textarea.charcount").on("input", function() {
  YourFunction($(this))
});

function YourFunction($this) {
  var maxlength = $this.attr("maxlength");
  var currentLength = $this.val().length;
  var $div = $this.next('div')
  if (currentLength >= maxlength) {
    $div.addClass('limit');
    $div.text("Character limit reached!");
  } else {
    $div.removeClass("limit");
    $div.text(maxlength - currentLength + " charachters left");
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks but I'm getting a "TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined" with this

Comment: Ok, I forgot to replace `$(this)` with `$this`.

Comment: I know, can't understand that either??

Comment: It's calling the error not from your code but from the jQuery.js itself - maybe it's a version prblem - here the full message: TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined[Weitere Informationen]
jquery.js:7760:4

Comment: Can you try again since I replace `$(this)` with `$this`? Just wonder if this occurs the error.

Comment: Hi Hikarunomemory - great - works fine now withg your change :-)

Answer (score 0):

remove the first part , and just trigger the input event on ready , like below

```
$(function() {
  $("textarea.charcount").on("input", function() {
    var maxlength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
    var currentLength = $(this).val().length;
    if (currentLength >= maxlength) {
      $(this).next('div').addClass('limit');
      $(this).next('div').text("Character limit reached!");
    } else {
      $(this).next('div').removeClass("limit");
      $(this).next('div').text(maxlength - currentLength + " charachters left");
    }
  });

  $("textarea.charcount").trigger("input");
});
```

Comment: Except trigger will also execute all functions bound to input event too, and not just this one.